# how to print inline in python strings and function

Tags: python

How to print a string and funtion(print) on the same line:
For example:-

```
def displayHand(hand):
      print({1:2,2:3})
```

know how can i get a print like this ( Current Hand:{1:2,2:3} )

Comment: `print("Current Hand", {1:2,2:3})`

Comment: ^ or `print('Current Hand: {}'.format({1:2,2:3} ))`

Comment: I want to print this on the same line like ( print('Current Hand:'), displayHand(hand) ) but when I run it the dictionary print out on the next line

Answer (score 2):

Add an `end=" "` to your first print call:

```
print('Current Hand:', end=" ")
```

Full code:

```
In [416]: def displayHand(hand):
     ...:       print(hand)
     ...:     

In [417]: hand = {1:2, 2:3}
     ...: print('Current Hand:', end=" ")
     ...: displayHand(hand)
     ...: 
Current Hand: {1: 2, 2: 3}
```

If you're using python 2, you'd need:

```
print 'Current Hand:',
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def displayHand(hand):
    print ('Current Hand: %s'%(hand))

print displayHand({'1':2, '2':3})
```